# how to write async storage value return function in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

how to write a method to return async storage value in react native.
I have done login authentication using Context API.

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
import { BASE_URL } from "../constants/Const";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    // loading & usertoken hooks
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [userToken, setuserToken] = useState(null);



    //login method
    const login = async (email, password) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        //fetch method to get access token
        fetch(`${BASE_URL}/sign_in`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password,
            })
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                //console.log("login auth ", json)
                if (json.responseCode == 200) {
                    try {
                        setuserToken(json.responseData.access_token);
                        //storing usertoken value in react-native encrypted storage
                        AsyncStorage.setItem("userToken", json.responseData.access_token)
                        //console.log("user token",userToken);
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        console.log("Error while saving user token data", userToken);
                    }
                }
                //showing invalid email & password alert messaqge
                else {
                    Alert.alert('Invalid email or password.');
                    return;
                }


            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

        setIsLoading(false);
    }
    //logout method
    const logout = async () => {

        setIsLoading(true);
        //setting user token as null 
        setuserToken(null);
        try {
            //removing usertoken value in react-native encrypted storage
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem("userToken");

        } catch (error) {
            // There was an error on the native side
            console.log("Error while removing data", error);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);

    }
    // checking user is already logged in each time when app starts
    const isLoggenIn = async () => {
        try {

            setIsLoading(true);
            //let userToken = await EncryptedStorage.getItem("userToken");
            let userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");

            //console.log("accesed user token",userToken);
            setuserToken(userToken);
            setIsLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error retrieving data", error);

        }
    }
    
    const [connected, setConnected] = useState(true);

   
    

    useEffect(() => {
        isLoggenIn();
        // Subscribe
        const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
            // console.log("Connection type", state.type);
            // console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
            setConnected(state.isConnected);
        });
        //clean up function
        return () => unsubscribe();

    }, [])
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ login, logout, isLoading, userToken ,connected,}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

in Redux slice file I want access token values to make a fetch request to a server.i defined getAccessToken Method to return accessToken value but it is not returning value

DataSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useState } from 'react';

import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import { BASE_URL } from '../constants/Const';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';



//const accessToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNjM2YTFlNTc4YWNlNTRjM2E5OWE4YWI2IiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2Njg0MDY2MzgsImV4cCI6MTY2ODQ2MDYzOH0.i_GHy2K91I0_159AIpQ4m2eFUmyXYFmF3_0sQ-o_x-w";

//user token function
const getAcessToken = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    return token;

}
var userToken = getAcessToken();

// get and delete method request options
const getDeleteRequestOptions = (methodType) => {
     
    return {
        method: methodType,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'autherization': userToken
        }
    }

}


// save and edit method request options
const saveEditRequestOptions = (methodType, data) => {
    console.log("img uri",data.imgUri)
    const imgData = new FormData();
    imgData.append('first_name', data.firstName);
    imgData.append('last_name', data.lastName);
    imgData.append('phone', data.phoneNo);
    imgData.append('email', data.email);
    imgData.append('image', { uri: data.imgUri, name: 'image', type: 'image/jpg' });

    return {
        method: methodType,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'autherization': userToken
        },


        body: imgData

    }
};



// fetch data
export const getData = createAsyncThunk('fetch', async ({pageNo,limit}) => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/list_profile?page_number=${pageNo}&limit=${limit}`, getDeleteRequestOptions('GET'))
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            //returning json receive array
            if(pageNo === 0 && limit === 0){
            return {data:json.receive,fetchAllData:true};
            }
            return {data:json.receive,fetchAllData:false};

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
});
// delete data
export const deleteData = createAsyncThunk('delete', async ({id}) => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/delete_profile/${id}`, getDeleteRequestOptions('DELETE',userToken))
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });

});


// save data  
export const saveData = createAsyncThunk('save', async (data) => {
    
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/add_profile`, saveEditRequestOptions('POST', data))
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
            if (json.responseCode === 211) {
                Alert.alert('Input Error', json.responseMessage, [
                    { text: "OK" }
                ])
                return;
            }
            console.log("save responese message ", json.responseMessage);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });



});

// edit data 
export const editData = createAsyncThunk('edit', async (data) => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/update_profile/${data.id}`, saveEditRequestOptions('PUT', data))
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log("edit data response message ", json.responseMessage);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });

});



const initialState = {
    masterData: [],
    filteredData: [], //array to implement search
    allData:[],
    imgurl: '',

};

export const dataSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'crud',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        filterData: (state, action) => {
            state.filteredData = action.payload;
        },
        selectedImage: (state, action) => {
            state.imgurl = action.payload;
        },
       




    },
    extraReducers: {
        // get data
        [getData.pending]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('fetching data is pending');
        },
        [getData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('data fetched successfully')
            if (!action.payload) {
                Alert.alert('Network error', 'Data Fetching is Failded Please try Again later.', [
                    { text: "OK" }
                ])
                return;
            }
            console.log(action.payload.fetchAllData)
            if(action.payload.fetchAllData){
                //console.log("inside fetch all data")
                state.allData = action.payload.data;
               
            }
            state.masterData = action.payload.data;
            state.filteredData = action.payload.data;
        },
        [getData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('fetching request rejected');
        },

        // delete data
        [deleteData.pending]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('delete data is pending');
        },
        [deleteData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('data deleted successfully');
        },
        [deleteData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('data delete request rejected');
            Alert.alert('Delete Data Failure', 'Deleting Data Failed. Please try Again later.', [
                { text: "OK" }
            ])
        },

        // save data
        [saveData.pending]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('saving data is  pending');
        },
        [saveData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {

            console.log('data saved successfully');


        },
        [saveData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('data save request rejected');
            Alert.alert('Data Save Failure', 'Data Save Failed. Please try Again later.', [
                { text: "OK" }
            ])

        },
        //edit data
        [editData.pending]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('edit data is  pending');
        },
        [editData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('data edited successfully');

        },
        [editData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
            console.log('edit data request rejected');
            Alert.alert('Data Edit Failure', 'Edit data Failed. Please try Again later.', [
                { text: "OK" }
            ])

        },

    },


})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { filterData, selectedImage } = dataSlice.actions;


export default dataSlice.reducer
```

```
i want to get access token values
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you are not calling `getAccessToken()` with `await` like this:

```
var userToken = await getAcessToken();
```

since it is asynchronous function.